# List duplicate data concatenation in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

i am a newbie in python and facing issue in getting this output

```
 a = [('textVerify', 'AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('textVerify', 'F7', 'test1>'),('audioVerify', '091;0'), ('imageVerify', 'duck.gif'),('imageVerify', 'egg.gif')]
```

i want to create a new list which should hold all the 0th unique element like

```
  audioVerify,imageVerify,textVerify
```

so the result expected is

```
 ['textVerify',(('AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('F7', 'test1>'))  'audioVerify', ('091;0'),  ('imageVerify', ('duck.gif','egg.gif')]
```

Comment: That's not an appropriate data structure. A dictionary would make much more sense, especially a defaultdict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in a:
...     d[item[0]].append(item[1:])
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'textVerify': [('AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), 
('F7', 'est1>')], 'imageVerify': [('duck.gif',), ('egg.gif',)], 
'audioVerify': [('091;0',)]})
```

Now you can access its elements by name/index:

```
>>> d['textVerify']
[('AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('F7', 'test1>')]
>>> d['textVerify'][0][0]
'AH'
```

If you need to preserve the order of the dictionary keys, you can use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), together with the `.setdefault()` method, as described by Ashwini Chaudhary:

```
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for x in a:
...     d.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1:])
...
>>> d
OrderedDict([('textVerify', [('AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('F7', 'test1>')]), 
('audioVerify', [('091;0',)]), ('imageVerify', [('duck.gif',), ('egg.gif',)])])
```

Comment: though `dict.setdefault()` is kinda faster than `defauldict()`.

Comment: on using this how to preserver the order of dict entry:

Comment: @Ragav: If order is relevant, you can use an `OrderedDict`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker : did the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `dict.setdefault()`, this is slightly faster than `defaultdict()` at least for small lists.:

```
>>> a
[('textVerify', 'AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('textVerify', 'F7', 'test1>'), ('audioVerify', '091;0'), ('imageVerify', 'duck.gif'), ('imageVerify', 'egg.gif')]
>>> d={}
>>> for x in a:
...     d.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1:])
... 
>>> d
{'audioVerify': [('091;0',)], 'textVerify': [('AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('F7', 'test1>')], 'imageVerify': [('duck.gif',), ('egg.gif',)]}

>>> d["audioVerify"]
[('091;0',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> _ = [d[i[0]].append(i[1:]) for i in a]
>>> d['textVerify']
[('AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('F7', 'test1>')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('textVerify', 'AH', 'SELECT SERVICES'), ('textVerify', 'F7', 'test1>'),('audioVerify', '091;0'), ('imageVerify', 'duck.gif'),('imageVerify', 'egg.gif')]

c=set(i[0] for i in a)
d=dict()
for i in c:
        m=[]
        for v in a:
                if v[0]==i:
                        m.extend(list(v[1:]))
        if len(m) !=0:
                d[i]=m

print(d)
```